# Anyone have working code showing how to get a simple widget to display using dot42 for android?

Tags: android, widget, sample, dot42

I am new to dot42 (liking it so far) but cannot get a simple widget to work.  Rather than get into specific issues I am hitting, does anyone know of sample code showing a working widget using dot42?  Just looking for a hello world widget using dot42.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As still I'm newbie in `dot42`, I'm able to do a working widget. Here's step-by-step method I've done (I assume your work in Visual Studio 2010 +):

> Project(Right click) > Add > New item > AppWidget > Ok(done!)